# Cannot connect to Azure Event Hub using Java

Tags: java, node.js, azure-eventhub

I am using Java 17 to listen to events from Azure Event Hub. I only have the connection string and the event hub name. According to the Microsoft docs, I can do something like this:

```
EventHubConsumerAsyncClient consumer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
                .credential(connectionString, eventHubName,
                        new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
                                .build())
                .consumerGroup(EventHubClientBuilder.DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME)
                .buildAsyncConsumerClient();

        // Obtain partitionId from EventHubConsumerAsyncClient.getPartitionIds()
        String partitionId = "0";
        EventPosition startingPosition = EventPosition.latest();

        // Keep a reference to `subscription`. When the program is finished receiving events, call
        // subscription.dispose(). This will stop fetching events from the Event Hub.
        //
        // NOTE: This is a non-blocking call and will move to the next line of code after setting up the async
        // operation.  If the program ends after this, or the class is immediately disposed, no events will be
        // received.

        Disposable subscription = consumer.receive().subscribe(partitionEvent -> {
            PartitionContext partitionContext = partitionEvent.getPartitionContext();
            EventData event = partitionEvent.getData();

            System.out.printf("Received event from partition '%s'%n", partitionContext.getPartitionId());
            System.out.printf("Contents of event as string: '%s'%n", event.getBodyAsString());
        }, error -> {
            // This is a terminal signal.  No more events will be received from the same Flux object.
            System.err.print("An error occurred:" + error);
        }, () -> {
            // This is a terminal signal.  No more events will be received from the same Flux object.
            System.out.print("Stream has ended.");
        });
```

but I always get a connection reset error:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: Connection reset, errorContext[NAMESPACE: BLABLABLA. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A]
Caused by: com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: Connection reset, errorContext[NAMESPACE: BLABLABLA. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:85) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler.notifyErrorContext(ConnectionHandler.java:351) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler.onTransportError(ConnectionHandler.java:253) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:191) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291) ~[proton-j-0.33.8.jar:na]
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.run(ReactorExecutor.java:91) ~[azure-core-amqp-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.5.11.jar:3.5.11]
Caused by: com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: Connection reset, errorContext[NAMESPACE: BLABLABLA. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A]
```

I've ommited the namespace since I cannot share it publicly.

But, using Node.js I can connect and receive events without any issues, doing the following:

```
const consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, connectionString, eventHubName);

async function startConsumer() {
    const subscription = consumerClient.subscribe({
        processEvents: async (events, context) => {
            for (const event of events) {
                await processEvent(event);
            }
        },
        processError: async (error) => {
            console.error("An error occurred: ", error);
        }
    });

    // Wait for a few seconds to receive events
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));

    // Stop the consumer
    await subscription.close();
    await consumerClient.close();
}

async function processEvent(eventData) {
    // some code here, cannot share
}

startConsumer().catch((error) => {
    console.error("An error occurred: ", error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct the Java consumer, you're passing your connection string along with a token credential via `.credential`.  This is going to cause the connection string to be interpreted as the fully qualified namespace *(ex. mything.servicebus.windows.net)* and used as the endpoint to connect to.

To use the connection string, you'll want to call the builder's `connectionString` method:

```java
EventHubConsumerAsyncClient consumer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
    .connectionString(connectionString, eventHubName)                
    .consumerGroup(EventHubClientBuilder.DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME)
    .buildAsyncConsumerClient();
```

Comment: that worked just fine, thanks a lot!